# Docker on OpenStack. npm stuck after fetch and before lifecycle

Tags: docker, npm, openstack, npm-install

**Background**:
The goal is to dockerize an Angular website and run it on an OpenStack VM. There is a lot of work to dockerize nmp so my collegue found this already prepared docker image that we use. The Angular website is created to fit the version of npm node.js that this docker is based on.

**Problem:**
We develop the code on a Ubuntu VM that is running on a Windows computer, and locally this works fine. The problem occurs when we try to build the docker image on an OpenStack ubuntu VM. We first thought it was a network problem but after some investigation we noticed that npm does fetch packages and it gets them. After fetching all the packages it just stops and give no response, but this may be cancelled by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. On the local VM it continues after fetching all the packages with doing a lifecycle thing on the fetched packages. This never gets done on the Open Stack VM.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

RUN echo http://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/alpine/v3.5/main > /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo http://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/alpine/v3.5/community >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update && apk add nginx

COPY app-gui/package.json app-gui/package-lock.json ./

## RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ && npm ping [--registry https://registry.npmjs.org/]

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force
RUN npm config set loglevel info 

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app
COPY bletf-gui/ .

#Setup nginx
RUN cat ./nginx/default.conf
COPY app-gui/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html && mkdir -p /run/nginx

CMD sed -i -e 's|\$HOST|'"${API_HOST}"'|g' src/environments/environment.prod.ts && \
    $(npm bin)/ng build --prod && cp -R ./dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/ && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

If there is any other information needed I will try to give that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the MTU value inside the Docker container and compare it with the host machine MTU value..

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep mtu
```

You can either change the configuration of mtu from Docker daemon config or at container level to match each other

From Docker daemon level
    /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --mtu=1450

At container level
    docker run -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN IMAGE_NAME
    # ifconfig eth0 mtu 1400